# Finding 2's complement of negative no

Tags: math, programming-languages, numbers, computer-science

We assume that 4bit 2's complement system is used to represent both positive and negative numbers

```
Suppose  we have to find 2's complement of no.  3
We can subtract this no. with 2^4
              that is ,                   
                           = 2^4 - 3
                           = 13  
                           =1101 (which represent -3 , in 2's complement system)

//* there is another way of finding 2's complement , taking 1's complemen of the 
    number and add 1 to it.
```

In the book rule is given to subtract two no.

**Rule :**  to subtract two no X and Y , that is X - Y , **form 2's complement of no. Y** and add it to X.

Suppose we have to subtract  two no. (-7) and (-5), then according to rule, we need to find 2's complement of the no (-5), and then add it to (-7).

**Book solution :**

[image]

I need to know , how 2's complement of -5 is 0101.

Answer (score 1):

To find the 2's complement of a number you:

- invert the bits
- add 1

Example (2s complement of 5):

- 5 = `0101` in binary
- invert the bits:

  `1010`
- Add 1:

  `1011` <- 2s complement of 5 is `1011`

Example (2s complement of -5):

- -5 = `1011` in binary
- invert the bits:

  `0100`
- Add 1:

  `0101` <- 2s complement of -5 is `0101`

Comment: but the no is not 5 , it is -5 and in 2's complement system , bit representation for -5 is 1011.

Comment: If you perform the same 2s complement operation on a negative number you will get the positive number.

Comment: and how can we find the same value by subtracting it from 2^4 ?

Comment: `2^4 - (the number) = (2s complement)` for 4 bits, and you only use the least significant 4 bits. So `2^4 - (-5) = 21`, which is `0b10101` but since we only want the least significant 4 bits the 2s complement would be `0b0101`, which is 5.